# Python: Make so I can visualize the information from a database from a Qt Designer made user interface to another

Tags: python, database, pyqt5

I am making a program that consist of a calendar with which I can add/remove/modify events that have a name, location, time, date (visualized by the position in the calendar), organizer and a short description.
Now the problem is that since I have two interfaces (one with the calendar itself and only the name of the events on a selected date, and the other being a view of a specific date showing the rest of the data), I want the data from a day chosen in the first to be shown in the second, but I don't know how I could do it.

I tried to pass data directly, but either I don't understand how or made too many mistakes, since it did not work, and I don't know how to use queries in two different files (one for the first view and another for the second) with the data from only the first file.

For now the program can add an event, look at different days of the calendar and (when I click on a day in the list) open the second page of the interface, even if it's empty of all the data.

Basically I need help finding a way to just click on a event of a day and make so all the data of the event get passed to the second page, and making so that if I close the page (or click back which I'll implement later) it resets and I can open another event.

Here's the code for almost anything (the database is a DB Browser database composed of the data of an event):

initializer.py

```
    def calendarDateChanged(self):
        dateSelected = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPyDate() #funzione di QCalendarWidget che indica la data selezionata, in forma di stringa PyDate e strftime che lo mette in giorno mese anno
        print("Data selezionata: ", dateSelected)
        self.updateTaskList(dateSelected)

    def updateTaskList(self, date):
        self.tasksListWidget.clear()

        db = sqlite3.connect("DatabaseCalendario.db") #il collegamento
        cursor = db.cursor() #fa il query (cosa gli chiedo del database)

        query = "SELECT name, time FROM tasks WHERE date = ?"
        row = (date,)
        results = cursor.execute(query, row).fetchall() #permette di eseguire i query sul database
        for result in results:
            item = QListWidgetItem(str(result[0])) #result [1] è quello completo, 0 è il task
            self.tasksListWidget.addItem(item)

    def saveChanges(self):
        db = sqlite3.connect("DatabaseCalendario.db")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        date = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPyDate()

        for i in range(self.tasksListWidget.count()):
            item = self.tasksListWidget.item(i)
            task = item.text()
            if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                query = "UPDATE tasks SET completed = 'YES' WHERE name = ? AND date = ?"
            else:
                query = "UPDATE tasks SET completed = 'NO' WHERE name = ? AND date = ?"
            row = (name, date,)
            cursor.execute(query, row)
        db.commit()

        messageBox = QMessageBox()
        messageBox.setText("Changes saved.")
        messageBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        messageBox.exec()

    def addNewTask(self):
        db = sqlite3.connect("DatabaseCalendario.db")
        cursor = db.cursor()

        newName = str(self.taskLineEdit.text())
        date = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPyDate()
        newLocation = str(self.taskLineEdit1.text())
        newTime = str(self.taskLineEdit2.text())
        newOrganizer = str(self.taskLineEdit3.text())
        newDescription = str(self.taskLineEdit4.text())

        query = "INSERT INTO tasks(name, date, location, time, organizer, description) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        row = (newName, date, newLocation, newTime, newOrganizer, newDescription,)

        cursor.execute(query, row)
        db.commit()
        self.updateTaskList(date)
        self.taskLineEdit.clear()

    def openWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_SecondWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    '''def moveData(self):
         side = self.tasksListWidget.currentRow() #questo è il problema, non riesco in alcun modo a selezionare solamente
         # la riga e il suo interno allo stesso tempo devo trovare un modo per popolare quella riga in particolare con
         # oggetti invece che con solo un nome e un quadrato di controllo
         print(side)
         #assegna cosa a seconda finestra
         #self.ui.labelReceiver.setText(row)
         self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
         self.ui = Ui_SecondWindow()
         self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
         self.window.show()'''

    '''def tagImportListClicked(self):
        print("You clicked the widget")
        row = self.tasksListWidget.currentRow()
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_SecondWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()
        #assegna cosa a seconda finestra
        self.ui.labelReceiver.setText(row)'''


    '''def moveData(self):
        loadUi("mainCalendarioSelezionato.ui", self)

        self.tasksListWidget.clear()
        db = sqlite3.connect("DatabaseCalendario.db")
        cursor = db.cursor()'''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

initializer2.py

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        loadUi("mainCalendarioSelezionato.ui", self)
        self.modifyButton.clicked.connect(self.updateWidget)

    def updateWidget(self, date):
        self.tasksListWidget.clear()

        db = sqlite3.connect("DatabaseCalendario.db") #il collegamento
        cursor = db.cursor() #fa il query (cosa gli chiedo del database)

        query = "SELECT name, time FROM tasks WHERE date = ?"
        row = (date,)
        results = cursor.execute(query, row).fetchall() #permette di eseguire i query sul database
        for result in results:
            item = QListWidgetItem(str(result[0])) #result [1] è quello completo, 0 è il task
            self.tasksListWidget.addItem(item)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = Window()
        window.show()
        sys.e

xit(app.exec())
```

The rest of the code is the Qt Designer parts, which if needed I can provide.

I hope I am not making stupid questions, but I am really green with Python and without a dedicated tutorial I don't know what to do.

Comment: Which is the main file? Where is the rest of the first code snippet, and to what class those functions belong? Also, the second code will never work as expected, as the argument of a button `clicked` signal is always a bool, so `date` will probably be always equal to 0. [Here](//wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Tutorials) you can find some good PyQt tutorials, and, if I may, I'd suggest you to start with something *simpler* than what you're doing now, so that you can actually understand the basic mechanics of Qt before moving to something more complex.

Comment: @musicamante the fact is, that this is a university project, and all the other programs I made until now where a lot easier and almost never used more than one file, hell they never used Qt Designer (but still said to use it).
The main file is the first and I have no idea why it did not copy and paste all of it, the second one I know it does not work, and that's the point, I want it to select the same date I selected in the list widget, just doing that would be incredibly usefull.
Anyway I'll look at the tutorials

Comment: You can [edit] your question and fix its code with the missing part. If you need to get the current item of a QListWidget, use `currentItem()`. The fact that you're using more files (or Designer files) is a bit irrelevant: the concepts are still the same, as the widgets and their functions. I know that the learning curve of Qt may seem very steep after the first steps (that normally seem quite straightforward and easy to understand). I can only suggest you to carefully and patiently follow those tutorials, and, most importantly, always read the documentation of any function you're using.